# Cross-browser font-weight rendering

Tags: css, fonts, cross-browser, google-fonts

[Sorts Mill Goudy](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Sorts+Mill+Goudy) is a great-looking font, and renders beautifully on Chrome.

However, it doesn't seem to have a native bold-face.  (It does have italics, though.)

So, I suppose it is up to the browser to apply a "faux-bold" if the font-weight is set to bold.

It turns out that different browsers apply this "faux-bold" very differently.  In the case of Chrome, it looks wonderful at 800 font-weight, but Safari and Chrome don't take the same approach.  They are clearly trying to do something to make it bolder, but not doing what Chrome is.  The result is reminiscent of pre-unicode foreign language encodings trying to typeset themselves... each letter seems a bit too wide, and it just feels "off", especially compared to how Chrome handles it.

What is going on here?  Is there a way to export Chrome’s faux-bold as a font file (ttf or otherwise), and force other browsers to follow suit?

How can I achieve cross-browser consistency here?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
h1
{
  font-family: "Sorts Mill Goudy";
  font-weight:400;
  font-size:3em;
  text-align:center;
}

h1.b
{
  font-weight:800;
}
</style>
<h1>Test Text: Font-weight 400</h1>
<h1 class="b">Test Text: Font-weight 800</h1>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/1bc25a/pen/oNWOQoL

[Image: Side-by-side font renderings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvJvl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that what is going on here is actually every browser doing his own thing in font rendering. It may even get worse if you test in Edge. Every browser seems to take its own approach to rendering font weight and anti-aliasing. So since you don't find a native bold face somewhere, there might be little you can do :/

It might be comforting that you are not alone with this problem, as you can see here: https://blog.stephaniestimac.com/posts/2020/06/browser-fonts/

And it might be helpful remembering that Mr. Berners-Lee knew from the very beginning that those new kind of pages would be displayed on all kind of devices and therefore HTML and CSS are all about taking control away from the designer and giving it to the rendering device or user.

You might try and hack about a bit by detecting browsers and feeding them differen font weights, but I don't know if that will make things better, and I am pretty sure it might not be worth it.

Sorry, I fear this is not the kind of answer you wanted ...

Comment: I appreciate the confirmation that I'm not going crazy!

Comment: No, you are not. Just remember that you have to let some things go when it comes to HTML and CSS. It's normal and it's even intended :)